# ViewPager scroll through padding (like clipToPadding=false in ListView)

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with 4 Fragments, and I have padding t=on the ViewPager (to make the text in it format correctly).  However, it then looks like the next Fragment is coming out of thin air when I scroll to the next Fragment.  How can I make the sliding Fragment come from the edge of the screen (ignoring the padding)?

Basically, I want it to perform like setting clipToPadding=false in a ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the 4 fragments have the padding instead of the ViewPager is the only solution I know.

It is not 100% the same behavior, but it is pretty close.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is that not the same behavior?

Comment: The padding on a ListView works that you see the view scrolling over the padding it the content of it is longer than the ListView. So you see the "next" entry even when scrolled completely to the top. That is not the case on a ViewPager as you don't see the next Fragment on the padding but you see it scroll over the padding when you scroll. Was that understandable?

Comment: Yeah, I had to read it a couple times :), but I got it.  Thanks.  This is what I ended up doing, setting the padding on the Fragment layouts instead of the ViewPager.

Comment: Yeah, English is not my first language but I think my German version wouldn't have been better :) Glad you have a solution! :D